# How to change axis values' format to percent in R base plot

Tags: r, visualization

I'm trying to change the format of y axis in R base plot i.e. plot(x, y, type='l'). I have y values as numeric and I want values on axis to appear as %. How can I do that?

Comment: `plot(.., yaxt="n")`, and `axis(2, ylbl)` where `ylbl` is something you make that includes the `%` sign.

Comment: @r2evans how do I make ylbl, could you give example?

Comment: just multiple by 100? put % in the ylab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
x <- 1:3
y <- 1:3 / 4
plot(x, y, type = "l")
```

[image]

```r
plot(x, y, type = "l", yaxt = "n")
ylbl <- axTicks(side=2)
ylbl
# [1] 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7
axis(2, at = ylbl, labels = paste(100*ylbl, "%"))
```

[image]

Comment: By any chance, Iike there seems to be a space between value and % sign, is there a way to remove it. Thanks a ton.

Comment: use `paste0` instead or add `sep=""`, both can be found in [`?paste`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html)